# MMDrawerController - Open Left Drawer from a button in Center Drawer

Tags: objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I've created a MMDrawerController within my app delegate file and I'm having trouble trying to toggle open the left drawer from an action within the center view. Is this a possible thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in click event of your center view button.

```
[self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This mm_drawerController object is your MMDrawer object.

Comment: If I've initialised the mm_drawerController object in my App Delegate, how do I access it from within the centre view?

Comment: by replacing self.mm_drawerController with objAppDelegate.mm_drawerController where objAppDelegate your app delegate object.

Comment: What if I initialise it in an UIViewController?

Comment: If you created private method than you can access it using class object and if public than you can access using class name for that view-controller. Note: you can not access class variables in public method.